# I have some issues understanding recursion and especially when it happens twice in a return

Tags: c, recursion

I have some issues understanding recursion especially when it happens twice in a return. Can someone explain how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int buff[] = {0,-1,2,-3,-4,-4,6,-7,8,9};

int neg(int a[], int size) {
  if (size == 0) return 0;
  if (size == 1 && a[0] >= 0) return 0;

  if (size == 1 && a[0] < 0) return 1;
  else return neg(a, size/2) + neg(a + size/2, size - size/2);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  printf("Antalet negativa element %d\n", neg(buff, 10));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stpping through this in a debugger?

Comment: So it is called twice. First call is performed, completed. Then the second. Then they are summed up.

Comment: To start understanding recursion in general, google _factorial recursive_ and understand how that works; it's a very simple case of recursion.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Stepping through recursions is a very confusing experience I would say..

Comment: You also can put some `printf`s at strategic spots in your code. This will also help you to understand what happens

Comment: To start understanding recursion I would suggest to start with the mathematical concept of recursive definitions. A formula such as `f(0)=1; f(1)=1; f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)` is way easier to understand than what an implementing code is doing.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with that statement? It is an expression just as any other expression. The `return` does not change anything. You could rewrite it like this: `int ret; if (...) ret=1; else ret = neg(...)+neg(...); return ret;`

Comment: One of the things that may be helpful in understanding recursion is to focus on the specifications for the recursive function instead of on its implementation.  For example, "this function returns the number of negative elements in a contiguous region of an array of `int`."  If you implement that using recursion then you do so by supposing *a priori* that each recursive call has exactly the effect it is intended / documented to have.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Stepping through recursion gets much less confusing if you keep an eye on the call stack (backtrace) as you do it.

Comment: @NateEldredge If you have a tail recursion and some optimization, the call stack would be eliminated completely.

Comment: Okay, well, if you're stepping through anything as a beginner, you should have optimization turned off.

Comment: I understand the most basic recursion, the problem is when it happens twice in a return like in my code, can anyone go through my code step by step, would be very helpful!